# Ng Zorro Ant Design reactive form multiple error tips

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

How to give multiple error text for a single input field like required and minimum and maximum characters to the input field.

Comment: can you add a stackblitz for this?

Comment: I have the same question. Can someone give an example with `nzErrorTip`? I have no idea what first answer means.

Here's how to do it with [`nz-form-explain`][1]. But `nz-form-explain` is deprecated and we're supposed to use `nzErrorTip`.


  [1]: https://github.com/XT-Cheng/brick-travel-web/blob/689eea640a08080a3c634b2b233b62643d607e36/src/app/routes/passport/register/register.component.html#L9

Comment: How can I show `NzWarningTip` using ng-template. can anyone please suggest me ?

Answer (score 2):

https://ng.ant.design/components/form/en#components-form-demo-validate-reactive

When there are multiple tips in the same state, nzSuccessTipnzWarningTipnzErrorTipnzValidatingTip supports the passing TemplateRef<{ $implicit: FormControl } type, which can be used to switch tips after exporting FormControl via the template syntax.